# Better way to fit wires in electrical boxes?

Tags: electrical, wiring, cable-management

So in pretty much every video I watch with installing a ceiling light or fan they just sort of 'stuff' all the wired pigtails up in the box.

Is there a better way to do this? maybe it's my distrust of wire caps/connectors? I always feel like that seems sorta hazardous...or the wire caps might get disconnected?

Am I wrong? or is there a better way than just stuffing everything in a box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ever so gently stuff them in, but there really isn't all too much that you can do - about the same with any wiring.

The 'technique' that I learned is to push one side in first, getting the majority of it in there, and then roll the device onto/into the box to push the rest in.

Just tighten the screws good enough and you'll have no problems.

Answer (score 3):

Wire nuts (the proper word for caps) are just one way to make a splice (join two connectors).

Nuts are widely accepted by people in the trade as the official way to do it, and if you use good wire nuts and use them properly, you have nothing to worry about.

When I use a wire nut, I tighten it until i think all the conductors are well attached.  Then I pull each individually with significant force to see it it will break free from the rest.  If they are all snug, I continue to tighten the nut causing the conductors to twist around eachother which acts as a mechanical fastener/strain releif in addition to just the nut, which really, is fine on its own.

If you want to take it a step further, you can ziptie them together once the nut is on and tested, and then use electrical tape after that to seal the bottom of the nut.  (Overkill, by far.)

They also make water proof wire nuts that have some sort of goo in them.

And there's other ways to make splices.  Even approved by the NEC assuming that applies to you or you want to follow the NEC.  Home depot has terminal blocks that you push wires into individually one at a time. Split-bolts and solid terminal blocks are common for large gagues.

Here's just a few options from just one vendor.  http://www.idealind.com/products/wire_termination/

Mechanically fastening wires together before they enter the splice would help keep them together under extraordinarily violent vibration.  But generally speaking, anything severe enough to knock regular old wire nuts loose inside a normal junction box is going to rip any house off its foundation and reduce it to splinters.  Extreme overkill.

Twist them on and have some faith.  Or get someone more experienced to double check you the first few times.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fold the wires to the back of the box, which should help, but to some extent you're really counting on the splice to be secure.  Wire nut connections when done right are very secure, but there is some skill / know how involved.  This type of connector:

[image: Ideal In-Sure]

makes a very secure connection, and they're very easy to use.  You can see through the clear plastic to make sure the wire is fully inserted.

Answer (score 0):

> **Is there a better way to do this?**

There are certainly *different* ways to do this.

[image]

A typical UK ceiling-rose for a pendant lamp. Wires are secured by screw terminals in brass blocks which are built into the plastic-bodied ceiling-rose.

In case you are wondering, cables at top are are loop-in, loop-out, switch (note brown tape on switched live). [Source](http://www.diy.com/help-advice/how-to-fit-ceiling-lights/CC_npcart_400211.art). There is strain-relief for the pendant cable at bottom.

For junctions in walls or ceiling voids there are similar junction boxes with built-in connectors.

Where those cant be used, UK electricians commonly uses unanchored screw-terminal blocks and, as you describe, just scrunch the wiring up to fit back in the box. I don't know whether properly tightened screw-terminal blocks are less prone to loosening than US wiring nuts, I imagine so.

Obviously, none of these solutions are likely to be available in the US and may not be approved in US local code.